# Set language in Laravel query builder

Tags: sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I'm having this simple query:

```
 $connection->table('bon_transfert')->insert($data)
```

Executing this query will sometimes return this error:

```
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value
```

It's easy to understand that the object $data contains a date with a wrong format.

If i'm writing the full query it will be easy to overcome this problem by adding 'set language french' at the beginning of the query like

```
set language french insert into bon-tansfert ....
```

But in my case i'm not writing the full query and i want to use the Laravel query builder:

I have tried the following line but it didn't work:

```
$connection->table('bon_transfert')->insert($data)->setlocale('fr');
```

Comment: are you using carbon? can we see how $data gets built? e.g. Carbon::createFromFormat('dd/mm/Y', $value)->toDateTimeString()

Comment: $timestamp = '2014-02-06 16:34:00';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Europe/Paris');
$date->setTimezone('UTC');

Comment: thanks for the replay, yeah i'm using carbon but the problem that following your exemple $timestamp could be at any format like '29/05/2019 15:12:03' for exemple so in this case your code will return 'Unexpected data found' error

Comment: I assume "could be in any format" is completely outside of your control? Because that sounds like a recipe for disaster.  if a date comes to you as 05/05/03 and you have no idea of the format... well I'll leave you to fill the blanks.